# My profile picture of SO not appearing on Google search

Tags: discussion

If I searched my name in Google for Images, I used to see my SO profile picture some days back. From nearly a week this is not happening. Whats happening? BTW, if I just Google my name my SO profile link is displayed in one of the results.

Comment: Misleading title.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Kindly edit..

Answer (score 1):

Goggle search engine is working differently. So don't know why your profile picture is not listing in google image search.

Google has its own algorithm to crawl the websites and other things to show the listing. Also google says that they are listing highly visited websites and other things they are listing at top.

May be because of these reasons your profile picture was showing in image search some days back and not showing now-a-days.